# Would a multiclassed Arcane Trickster rogue 3 / wizard 1 have only three 1st-level spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, multi-classing, rogue, spell-slots

I am new to multiclassing and new to spells with 5e.

Currently I am a Level 3 Rogue (Arcane Trickster) and just leveled up to level 4. For my fourth level, I was going to put a level into the wizard class as it makes sense for my backstory. However, I'm confused by the calculation for determining what spell slots I have.

According to the [multiclass spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/customization-options#Spellcasting) rules in the PHB (p. 164-165), to determine what spell slots I have, I would take my rogue level divided by 3 and then rounded down (1), and add it to my number of levels in the wizard class (1), for a total of 2.

Then looking at the 2nd row of the [Multiclass Spellcaster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/customization-options#MulticlassSpellcaster) table on page 165, it would seem that I'd have three 1st-level spell slots.

But that doesn't make sense to me, as I originally had two 1st-level spell slots as an Arcane Trickster rogue, and a 1st-level wizard has two 1st-level spell slots.

Would a multiclassed Arcane Trickster rogue 3 / wizard 1 have only three 1st-level spell slots? Or would they have four?

Comment: Related questions: [If I multiclass into 2 or more spellcasting classes, how do I determine my known/prepared spells?](/questions/151000), [Multiclass Spellcaster: Do the involved classes share the same pool of spell slots?](/questions/123731), [How do I determine how many spell slots I have when multiclassing?](/questions/167040)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## You would have only 3 first level spell slots.

Your interpretation of playing an Arcane Trickster 3/Wizard 1 multiclass is correct; you are effectively a 2nd level spellcaster with 3 first level spell slots, as per the rules on multiclassing (*PHB p.164*). You would know 3 first level spells from the wizard spell list because of your Arcane Trickster levels, 2 of which must be from the Enchantment or Illusion schools, and 6 spells first level spells from the Wizard spell list from your first level of being a Wizard, of which you could prepare 4 (your Wizard level + Intelligence Modifier).

Your spell slots can be used to cast spells of either class. something of note, if you were to take your 5th character level as a second Wizard level, you would now have 4 first level spell slots, and 2 second level spell slots, but you would not know any second level spells.  This is intentional; these second level spell slots can still function as intended for your first  level spells, allowing you to upcast applicable spells.

Comment: Not completely relevant, but I would recommend not taking a multiclass until after you've hit level 4; the ability increase is not very exciting, but important. As a rogue, having 20 DEX or an Arcane trickster having 18 INT (potentially a feat to match) will make a notable increase in your combat effectiveness.